# How to create a Pyomo Model of a Process with Variable Interactions?

Tags: optimization, pyomo

I am working on a process modeling problem in Pyomo where I have two components, Class Component A and Class Component B, and a class Master model that connects them. In this setup, a variable in Component A should serve as an input variable to Component B. I've defined the following constraint in the master model to establish this relationship:

`model.component_a.model.out_variable[t] == model.component_b.model.input_variable[t]`

However, I'm encountering the following error:

`ValueError: Error retrieving component out_variable[1]: The component has not been constructed.`

I'm using Pyomo for modeling and optimization. Can anyone please provide guidance on how to correctly set up this process model and constraints within the master model while avoiding the "component has not been constructed" error? What's causing this error and how to resolve it? Below is the entire code

**Code**

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# Class A
class ComponentA:
    def __init__(self, time_steps, max_value, min_value, efficiency, extra_power):
        self.model = pyo.Block()
        self.time_steps = time_steps
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.min_value = min_value
        self.efficiency = efficiency
        self.extra_power = extra_power
        self.define_params()
        self.define_variables()
        self.define_constraints()

    def define_params(self):
        # Parameters for Component A
        self.model.max_value = pyo.Param(self.time_steps, initialize=self.max_value)
        self.model.min_value = pyo.Param(self.time_steps, initialize=self.min_value)
        self.model.efficiency = pyo.Param(self.time_steps, initialize=self.efficiency)
        self.model.extra_power = pyo.Param(self.time_steps, initialize=self.extra_power)

    def define_variables(self):
        # Variables for Component A
        self.model.in_variable = pyo.Var(self.time_steps, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
        self.model.out_variable = pyo.Var(self.time_steps, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    
    def define_constraints(self):
        # Constraints for Component A
        self.model.input_limit = pyo.Constraint(self.time_steps, rule=lambda model, t: (model.min_value[t], model.in_variable[t], model.max_value[t]))
        self.model.production_constraint = pyo.Constraint(self.time_steps, rule=lambda model, t: model.in_variable[t] == model.out_variable[t] / model.efficiency[t] + model.extra_power[t])


# Class B
class ComponentB:
    def __init__(self, time_steps, max_input_value, max_output_value, efficiency_factor):
        self.model = pyo.Block()
        self.time_steps = time_steps
        self.max_input_value = max_input_value
        self.max_output_value = max_output_value
        self.efficiency_factor = efficiency_factor
        self.define_params()
        self.define_variables()
        self.define_constraints()

    def define_params(self):
        # Parameters for Component B
        self.model.max_input_value = pyo.Param(self.time_steps, initialize=self.max_input_value)
        self.model.max_output_value = pyo.Param(self.time_steps, initialize=self.max_output_value)
        self.model.efficiency_factor = pyo.Param(self.time_steps, initialize=self.efficiency_factor)
    
    def define_variables(self):
        # Variables for Component B
        self.model.input_variable = pyo.Var(self.time_steps, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
        self.model.extra_input_variable = pyo.Var(self.time_steps, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
        self.model.output_variable = pyo.Var(self.time_steps, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    
    def define_constraints(self):
        # Constraints for Component B
        self.model.input_constraint = pyo.Constraint(self.time_steps, rule=lambda model, t: model.input_variable[t] <= model.max_input_value[t])
        self.model.output_constraint = pyo.Constraint(self.time_steps, rule=lambda model, t: model.output_variable[t] <= model.max_output_value[t])
        self.model.efficiency_constraint = pyo.Constraint(self.time_steps, rule=lambda model, t: model.output_variable[t] == model.input_variable[t] * model.efficiency_factor[t] * model.extra_input_variable[t])

# Master Class C
class MasterModel:
    def __init__(self, time_steps, component_a_params, component_b_params):
        self.model_master = pyo.ConcreteModel()
        self.time_steps = time_steps
        self.component_a_params = component_a_params
        self.component_b_params = component_b_params
        self.demand = demand
        self.el_price = el_price
        self.hy_price = hy_price
        self.ir_price = ir_price
        self.define_sets()
        self.initialize_components()
        self.define_params()
        self.define_variables()
        self.define_constraints()
        self.define_objective()

    def define_sets(self):
        # Define sets for the model
        self.model_master.time_steps = pyo.Set(initialize=self.time_steps)
    
    def initialize_components(self):
        # Initialize components (Component A and Component B) as subcomponents
        self.model_master.component_a = ComponentA(self.model_master.time_steps, **self.component_a_params)
        self.model_master.component_b = ComponentB(self.model_master.time_steps, **self.component_b_params)
    
    def define_params(self):
        # Parameters for SteelPlant
        self.model_master.el_price = pyo.Param(self.model_master.time_steps, initialize=self.el_price)
        self.model_master.hy_price = pyo.Param(self.model_master.time_steps, initialize=self.hy_price)
        self.model_master.ir_price = pyo.Param(self.model_master.time_steps, initialize=self.ir_price)
        self.model_master.demand = pyo.Param(self.model_master.time_steps, initialize=self.demand)
    
    def define_variables(self):
        pass
    
    def define_constraints(self):
        # Constraints for Master Model
        def variable_match_rule(model, t):
            # Variable match constraint between Component A and Component B
            return model.component_a.model.out_variable[t] == model.component_b.model.input_variable[t]
    
        self.model_master.variable_match_constraint = pyo.Constraint(self.model_master.time_steps, rule=variable_match_rule)
    
        def demand_match_constraint_rule(model, t):
            # Demand match constraint
            return model.component_b.model.output_variable[t] == model.demand[t]
    
        self.model_master.demand_match_constraint = pyo.Constraint(self.model_master.time_steps, rule=demand_match_constraint_rule)
    
    def define_objective(self):
        # Objective function to minimize total cost
        def total_cost_rule(model):
            el_cost = sum(model.electricity_price[t] * model.component_a.model.in_variable[t] for t in model.time_steps)
            hy_cost = sum(model.hydrogen_price[t] * model.component_b.model.in_variable[t] for t in model.time_steps)
            ir_cost = sum(model.iron_ore_price[t] * model.component_b.extra_input_variable[t] for t in model.time_steps)
            return el_cost + hy_cost + ir_cost
    
        self.model_master.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=total_cost_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)
    
    def run_optimization(self):
        # Solve the optimization problem
        solver = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
        results = solver.solve(self.model_master, tee=True)
    
        if results.solver.status == pyo.SolverStatus.ok and results.solver.termination_condition == pyo.TerminationCondition.optimal:
            calculated_objective = pyo.value(self.model_master.objective)
            return results, calculated_objective
        else:
            return results, None

time_steps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
component_a_params = {
    'max_value': {1: 500, 2: 500, 3: 500, 4: 500, 5: 500}, 
    'min_value': {1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100, 5: 100}, 
    'efficiency': {1: 0.9, 2: 0.9, 3: 0.9, 4: 0.9, 5: 0.9}, 
    'extra_power': {1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 10} 
} 
component_b_params = {
    'max_input_value': {1: 1000, 2: 1000, 3: 1000, 4: 1000, 5: 1000}, 
    'max_output_value': {1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100, 5: 100}, 
    'efficiency_factor': {1: 0.95, 2: 0.95, 3: 0.95, 4: 0.95, 5: 0.95} 
} 
demand = {1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100, 5: 100} 
el_price = {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.1, 4: 0.1, 5: 0.1} 
hy_price = {1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 2.0} 
ir_price = {1: 50.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 50.0, 4: 50.0, 5: 50.0}

# Create the Master Model instance

master_model = MasterModel(time_steps, component_a_params, component_b_params)

# Run the optimization and print results
results, objective = master_model.run_optimization()

if objective is not None: 
    print(f"Optimal Objective Value: {objective:.2f}") 
    for t in time_steps: 
        component_a = master_model.model_master.component_a.model 
        component_b = master_model.model_master.component_b.model

        print(f"Time Step {t}:")
        print(f"  Out Variable A[{t}] = {pyo.value(component_a.out_variable[t]):.2f}")
        print(f"  Input Variable B[{t}] = {pyo.value(component_b.input_variable[t]):.2f}")
        print(f"  Output Variable B[{t}] = {pyo.value(component_b.extra_input_variable[t]):.2f}")
        print(f"  Output Variable B[{t}] = {pyo.value(component_b.output_variable[t]):.2f}")
else:
    print("Optimization did not converge to an optimal solution.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `Block`s on `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`are never being constructed.  Pyomo "constructs" (that is, populates them with data, thereby converting them from "abstract" containers to "concrete" containers filled with the appropriate modeling objects) when either the component is explicitly constructed (using `.construct()`), or when the component is "attached" to a constructed Block.

Here, the Blocks for ComponentA and ComponentB are never attached to the `model` block on ComponentC: you are attaching the `ComponentA` (and B) *objects* onto the block, but those objects are not Pyomo Components, so while they are attached, they are basically ignored when it comes to model construction.  There are a number of alternative ways to make this work.  The easierst is probably to just explicitly attach the block:

```py
# Master Class C
class MasterModel:
    def initialize_components(self):
        # Initialize components (Component A and Component B) as subcomponents
        self.component_a = ComponentA(self.model_master.time_steps, **self.component_a_params)
        self.component_b = ComponentB(self.model_master.time_steps, **self.component_b_params)
        self.model_master.component_a = self.component_a.model
        self.model_master.component_b = self.component_b.model
```

Alternatively, you could keep the structure you are working with now, and make `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` actually inherit from `ScalarBlock`.  This is a little more nuanced, especially if you would like to be able to treat `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` as indexed components (blocks).  If that is the use case you really want, you can make use of the `pyomo.core.base.block.declare_custom_block` class decorator.  This can get arbitrarily complex, for example, the base class for the unit operation model library in IDAES (see https://github.com/IDAES/idaes-pse/blob/main/idaes/core/base/process_block.py)